moved from Mac M1 to Mac M4. . ran into gradle issue on compile in VS Code using Flutter
I had a gradle problem with my M1 few months ago when I update Android  Studio code.  I stumbled a week trying all the suggestions.  Finally got it work. to compile.   I taking a flutter Udemy course.  so learning that and manage a new dev environment.
I migrated my M1 Macbook pro to a M4 Macbook pro few days ago.  I updated Android Studio by mistake at that time.  So now my VS IDE is failing on gradle build on my new M4 mac.   When I try to compile a simple Flutter app compiles fine on M1.
I check my M1
My android studio whos grade JDK jbr-17. 17.0.12 distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
My Mac M4 i have tried to setup same versions. but still getting error on compile for gradle.
This error:

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/bsanderson/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/bsanderson/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d9e926982c2c139ff9125eb7b6be4144/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/bsanderson/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d9e926982c2c139ff9125eb7b6be4144/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).

I have tried flutter clean to clear cache.
Questions
I check the gradle site for the table that shows compatable java and gradle versions.  I have tried setting to match but my M4 still errors on gradle build.
Short of wiping out my Dev environment and rebuild it.  not a big issue since I do have everything on github.  But really want to learn why this is happening to self fix in future.
thanks
bill sanderson

Update com.android.application plugin to version 8.3.2 in projectroot/android/settings.gradle file.
If you can't find this file you can create one at root of Android folder of Flutter project and copy paste below content:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    }

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.21" apply false
}

include ":app"


I spent the last two days trying to downgreade Android Studio JDK listed in FLutter Doctor as jdk ver 21.  I ended up.  Deleting Android Studio 100% env. Reinstall.  I have jdk 17 selected in Android gradle wrapper.   I have sdk jdk 17 selected for all environments on my mac.
I was able to finally compile past gradle errors today for first time.
My issue was Flutter Doctor --verbose was showing Androids jdk versions as:
Application finished.
bsanderson@Bill-M4-Macbook meals2 % flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.5, on macOS 15.1 24B2082 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.24.5 on channel stable at /Users/bsanderson/Development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision dec2ee5c1f (6 days ago), 2024-11-13 11:13:06 -0800
• Engine revision a18df97ca5
• Dart version 3.5.4
• DevTools version 2.37.3
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/bsanderson/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11)
• All Android licenses accepted.
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 16B40
✗ Unable to get list of installed Simulator runtimes.
• CocoaPods version 1.15.2
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11)
Which was throwing my into a tial spin try to get version jdk 17 to be used since flutter says it not support jdk 21 yet.
I am able to compile test code in flutter android app using VS Code IDE now.  yet flutter doctor --verbose is showing jdk 21 for Android config.
do not know why this is the case.
hope this help someone else...
